# Can I use org.eclipse.aether in Android app?

Tags: java, android, maven, aether

**Background**

I am trying to develop an Android App for coding,for which I want to parse gradle files and download the repositories which users needs.However,I install my app only to see an error which implies Android has got rid of Apache Http.But in Aether,the package is needed.

**What I have done**

1.I have try to use HttpLegacy.jar to use the deprecated api.But what is necessary for Aether.transport-http is removed ,which I mean is not in Android API or Legacy.jar.

2.Well,there maybe other resolutions such as create an Apache Http compact package by myself.If it wouldn't take too much time,I think,I would do this.

Please help me out.
Thank you for taking time to give me a hand.

Comment: Some third party Android System have removed Apache Http at all.I am so frustrated.

Comment: You can try to create a shandow-Jar of org.eclipse.aether and it's dependencies with a modified/shadowed package name so you won't run into conflicts with existing or missing Apache http libraries on Android.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your suggestion. I have used JarJar to modify the package name of Apache Http.Then I implementation what jars Apache Http needs to use. I have resolved it.